# Single sign-on with Laravel / suitecrm & moodle

Tags: php, laravel, moodle, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have three individual systems Laravel, SuiteCRM & Moodle, how can I use single sign-on (SSO) login for each & every system?

Comment: You can use SSO if you implement one of SSO protocols and connect your applications.

Comment: ok so can you tell me how to impliment SSO protocol

Comment: By using textual editor which you use to write code which implements SSO protocols.

Comment: ok good can you add this as a answer so that i can accept?

Answer (score 0):

While OAuth is not officially a single sign on (SSO) tool, it can be used.

Specific setup & configuration of OAuth 2 for the three mentioned applications can be found:

**Laravel:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport based on https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/

**SuiteCRM:** https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/version-8/configure-authentication/

**Moodle:** https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/OAuth_2_authentication